# SQL Server performance issues with very wide tables (400 columns). Need clarity on vertical partitioning?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with around 400 columns (4-5 million rows on average) and it has horrible performance even for count(*) or select x from y queries. The complicated queries that took seconds on a similar 30 columns table take hours on this even when the columns being accessed are same.

The obvious solutions I see are normalization, adding indexes and vertical partitioning. In this case, normalization is not possible because these extra columns are more or less random numbers and narrations related to each record. I am going to be adding indexes on the most used columns.

Now my questions are about vertical partitioning. I can divide the 400 columns into smaller tables, let's say 10 tables of 40 columns each. But -

1. Firstly, is there any real performance benefit of such vertical partitioning at all, considering all those tables will always be joined back for querying?
2. If there is a performance benefit, then what should be the criteria of partitioning? Should I just put the columns that are going to be mostly null, in the new tables? Or should I put the least frequently used columns, in the new tables? Or should I try to create the new tables so that the total row size of each table stays less than 8000 bytes?

The above approaches are what I found after many hours of searching. Any other approaches that work better for wide tables will be appreciated as well.

Comment: are you adhering to at least 3rd normal form?

Comment: Do you have a clustered index on this table? How's your page life expectancy (are you having issues holding this table in RAM)? Have you checked out the execution plan when doing any of these queries to see what exactly the problem is?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the [8060 in-row byte limit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981(v=sql.105).aspx) still applies to more recent versions of SQL Server.

Comment: Do your queries really need all 400 columns every time?  Are you performing calculations that could be kept in a persisted view instead?  Is this mostly read or is there a lot of writing of data?

Answer (score 0):

There is no performance gain to vertical partitioning if you are just going to join all the tables back again.  The performance gain comes from removing tables from the query.

As for performance overhead, if the id connect the two tables is a clustered primary key, then the performance should be very similar.

Many databases (particularly column-oriented databases) have built-in support for vertical partitioning.  That means that only the partitions with the columns are read in.  I don't think that SQL Server offers such support.

In your case, you can perhaps normalize your data.  This can actually be a big win, because the total volume of data being stored is much smaller than in the denormalized form -- and the overhead of join'ing might be minor.

You might also look at other possibilities:

- Revisit the data types on your columns.
- Determine whether sparse columns might solve your problems.
- Consider horizontal partitioning.
- Determine the best indexes for your queries.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Enterprise Edition provides columnstore indexes, which allows columns of a single table to be stored vertically, and optionally partitioned horizontally.  Columnstore indexes typically improve scan performance by orders of magnitude. Also, columnstore storage inherently compresses data such that it is common that storage requirements are reduced significantly.

Columnstore indexes are most suitable to DSS workloads that typically perform full scans.  SQL Server 2016 introduces columnstore enhancements that make columnstore indexes suitable for operational analytics too.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn817827.aspx.